# Стоит ли тестировать классы конфигурации spring? И если да, то как?

Tags: java, spring, junit

Не раз слышал, что тестами стоит покрывать 100% кода. Подобный подход вызвал ряд вопросов, например, нужно ли тестировать геттеры и сеттеры в модели, но тут, скорее, дело в смысле чем в реализации.
А вот для классов спринговой конфигурации я не понимаю как правильно написать тест, например, для такого метода

```
@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    em.setDataSource(dataSource());
    em.setPackagesToScan("com.example.model");

    JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
    em.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties());

    return em;
}
```

или

```
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource(){
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.h2.Driver");
    dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:h2:~/test");
    dataSource.setUsername( "sa" );
    dataSource.setPassword( "" );
    return dataSource;
}
```

И стоит ли, вообще, это делать?

Comment: *Не раз слышал, что тестами стоит покрывать 100% кода.* - вы еще должны были обязательно услышать о том, что тесты в принципе не нужны. Вообще нет никакого смысла тестировать конфигурацию.

Comment: Для этого ведь даже статические анализторы есть, чтобы прям 100% :)

Comment: И кто-то ещё должен протестировать тест, что он правильно тестирует и такая рекурсия продолжается до бесконечности. А когда же тогда программу составлять и ошибки править?